# Does a given subset of an infinite group generate a finite or infinite subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, finitely-generated, linear-groups

Consider a fixed infinite group, such as $SL(n, \mathbb{R})$. Let $S$ be a given finite subset of the elements of $SL(n, \mathbb{R})$, further suppose that $S$ is closed under inverses. Is there any way to decide whether $S$ generates a finite or infinite subgroup of $SL(n, \mathbb{R})$?

It would seem that choosing some random finite set of elements in $SL(n, \mathbb{R})$ (and their inverses), it should be far more likely that the set generates an infinite subgroup rather than a finite one. However, I am not sure how to begin trying to decide *a priori* whether or not a given subset generates a finite or infinite subgroup of the original group. My choice of $SL(n, \mathbb{R})$ was largely arbitrary; does this problem become any easier if instead we choose $SL(n, \mathbb{Z})$ or some other convenient matrix group?

Comment: The problem you describe is in general unsolvable, in a precise sense: there exists no algorithm (no Turing machine) that can solve this problem in general.

Comment: @CaptainLama But there is such an algorithm in the case of ${\rm SL}(n,{\mathbb Z})$.

Comment: By the way, what is the point of assuming that $S$ is closed under inverse? That makes no difference to the subgroup generated by $S$.

Comment: Yes, I'll make my comment more precise: there is no general answer to the problem for a general (let us say finitely generated, or even finitely presented) infinite group.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes you are right. I just wanted to make it explicit that we had access to the inverse elements of the set when considering the elements that can be expressed as a combination of the elements of the set.

Comment: @CaptainLama Are you inferring that by reduction of this problem to a general word problem? I think I intuitively can understand that there should be a reduction, but the proof isn't obvious to me. Could you explain that reduction, or point me somewhere where I could see that explicitly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with computing over the real numbers is that calculations can only be done to some fixed precision, so the accuracy of the answer is unclear.

But the answer to your question is yes for finitely generated subgroups $G$ of ${\rm GL}(n,K)$ where $K$ is a field in which you can do exact computation, such as a number field or a function field.

This algorithm is implemented in Magma and it is is amazingly fast  and, in the case when $G$ is finite, an isomorphic image of $G$ in ${\rm SL}(n,F)$ for some finite field $F$ is also returned.

This algorithm is described in the paper

Detinko, A.S., Flannery, D.L., O’Brien, E.A., 2013. Recognizing finite matrix groups over infinite fields. J. Symb. Comput. 50,
100–109.

Comment: For ${\rm SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$, an example of the problem you can have is if $S$ contains a member of form $$s=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos 2\pi t & -\sin 2\pi t \\  
\sin 2\pi t & \cos 2\pi t 
\end{bmatrix}$$i.e. a rotation of $t$ "turns" where $t\in\mathbb{R}$. Then if $t$ is a rational number, then the order of the member $s$ is finite, and if the other members of $S$ are also innocent enough, there is no reason why the subgroup generated by $S$ could not be finite. But if the number of turns $t$ is irrational, then the order of $s$ (and hence the subgroup generated by $S$) is infinite.